# Correspondence cohomology and Chern character

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

Let us consider the following situation: we have a proper map of smooth complex projective algebraic varieties $f:X \to Y$ of dimension $=n$. Let's say we moreover have a decomposition into the derived category of constructible sheaves $$Rf_*\mathbb{Q} \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}r_{i*}\mathbb{Q}[dim Z_i-n] $$ where $r_i:Z_i \to Y$ is a map finite and birational over a closed subvariety of $Y$.

This actually just a slight more general reformulation of what happens applying the decomposition theorem to the Hilbert scheme of a surface:my question is motivated by https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05330.pdf and https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2583.

Now the isomorphisms $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Q})\cong H^{*}(Y,Rf_{*}\mathbb{Q})$ and the other one
$H^{*}(Y,r_{i*}\mathbb{Q}[dim Z_i-n])=H^{*-n+dim Z_i}(Z_i,\mathbb{Q})$ give us a splitting $$H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Q})=\bigoplus_{i\in I}H^{*-n+dim Z_i}(Z_i,\mathbb{Q}) .$$

I'd like to prove the following statement: the summand $H^{*-n+dim Z_i}(Z_i,\mathbb{Q}) $ into $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Q}) $ is the image of the following map. Let us call $p:X \times Z_i \to X$ and $q:X \times Z_i \to Z_i$ the projection maps. We denote as $\Gamma_i \subseteq X \times Z_i $ the closed subvariety $X \times_{Y}Z_i$. We then define the map: $$H^{*-n+dim Z_i}(Z_i,\mathbb{Q}) \to H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Q}) $$ $$\alpha \to p_*(q^*\alpha \cup q^*td(Z_i) \cup ch(\mathcal{O}_{\Gamma_i})) .$$

I tried to prove but had no idea how to do that actually. I imagine Grothendick Riemann roch should be involved but do not know how.

Comment: $r_i$ can’t always be finite: Take the case blow up a point in a surface.

Comment: It was actually not clear but I'm assuming it to be an hypothesis

Comment: You are assuming $f$ is finite? Hilbert-Chow morphism for surfaces is not finite.

Comment: I'm assuming $f$ is proper, while the maps $r_i$ are finite

Comment: The decomposition theorem says $Rf_*\mathbb Q$ is the direct sums of the $IC$-complexes, which come from the local system over stratum $\bar{Y}_i$ of $Y$, where $f^{-1}(Y_i)\to Y_i$ is a smooth morphsim. If your $Z_i$ is not $f^{-1}(Y_i)$, I don't know where your decomposation theorem comes from.

Comment: Also, IC complexes are not just sheaf lower star map. They come from "lower sherik star map" and are complexes of sheaves usually not (shifts of) a single sheaf.

Comment: I'm assuming this decomposition as an hypothesis. I'm not saying this is always the case

Comment: Then it's better to give an example where it applies. Otherwise you are confusing the readers by the terming "Hilbert Chow morphism for a surface" since in general, it is referring to $S^{[n]}\to S^{(n)}$, in which your decomposition doesn't apply.

Comment: So, I added one more article to clear the context I'm working. This is actually not too relevant to the situation however I believe: do you have any suggestion on how to solve my question?